# The space of equall $L_1$ vectors

Tags: calculus, metric-spaces, normed-spaces

I am trying to understand norms. I have seen this common picture where we visualize the norms.
[image]

If I read it well. These curves, express the vectors with $L_p$ norm equal to $1$.
So if I wanted, for example the set of vectors with $|x|_1 = 2$ it will be a curve of the same shape of "radius $2$":

[image]

Is my visualization right?

Comment: It is correct but you can check for yourself! The set you looking for is $\{ v : ||v||_{1} = 1 \}=\{  (x,y) : |x| + |y| = 2\}$ restrict to each quadrant of the plane (i.e $x≥0, y≥0$ etc) and you'll see it's the union of the 4 segments you've drawn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your visualization is correct. In the first image, the curves represent the set of vectors with $L_p$ norm equal to $1$. Each curve corresponds to a different value of $p$.

In the second image, you correctly depicted the set of vectors with $|x|_1 = 2$. This set would indeed form a curve of the same shape as the "radius $2$" curve shown in the first image. The vectors on this curve have an $L_1$ norm (also known as the Manhattan norm or the sum of absolute values) equal to $2$.

Your understanding and visualization of these concepts are accurate.